# list of dicts swagger python

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

I want to specify a List of dict
and the keys of that dicts also in my swagger documentation,

```
class GetCustomerDetailsByIdPOUT(BaseModel):
    profileData: Customer
    scanData : Reports
    Scan: list
```

Currently, I am getting this

```
 "Scan": [
    "string"
  ]
```

You can also see in the image

[image]

I want something like this

```
"scans": [
                {
                "id": 0,
                "cameraId": 0,
                "reportId": 0,
                "sequenceNo": 1,
                "raw": [
                    "string"
                ],
                "spectrum": 1,
                "view": 1
                }
            ]
```

Comment: One option might be that you can define which response you expect when defining the route as a decorator. Example: `@router.get("/get", responses=your_response)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't provide the information on what list will contain. I don't know what you want to have in there, but for example:

```py
from typing import List

class GetCustomerDetailsByIdPOUT(BaseModel):
    profileData: Customer
    scanData : Reports
    Scan: List[MyScan]
```

within the type hinting you can provide the type - you class or build-in type, like `List[float]`.

For python <= 3.8 you should use typing module, for 3.9+ you don't have to. More on [typing aliases](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#type-aliases).

Also, if possible, think of aligning your naming convention to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). For example `profileData` -> `profile_data`.